# Magento grabbing the top 10 buyers

Tags: magento

I've been searching through the Magento tables, what fields would I use to grab the **top 10 buyers name** and the **total amount** each they spent.

i've been looking in the **flat_order** table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just having the total sales and the `customer_id` is enough:

```
SELECT customer_id,SUM(base_grand_total) AS total_sales 
FROM sales_flat_order
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

If you need the customer information in the same result, you'll have to join in some of the `customer_entity` tables, but if you're just looking for a quick report, the above should give you the top ten.

P.S. If you do want to tie in customer data, start with the `customer_entity` table, and things like their name appear to be in the `customer_entity_varchar` table.